# Location of Visual Studio 2008 SP1 After Installation

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I recently did an online installation of SP1 for VS 2008, where installation of VS 2008 + .NET 3.5 SP1 didn't provide me with templates for the Entity Framework and others.  I now have to move VS 2008 to another machine, and I don't want to wait out a 500MB download again.  Is there anywhere I can find the package downloaded by the download manager?

**Extra:** I have since located the .iso file, which I had previously downloaded.  It is called VS2008SP1ENUX1512962.iso, but the problem with this is that it includes updates for all VS features, and weighs in at >850 MB. It would be more 'download' damage than using the installer afresh if the .iso wasn't available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you be more specific with what type of Visual Studio you have?  Did you use the download manager for the Express Edition from the Microsoft or did you purchase and download it elsewhere?  Do you just want the SP1 installer or the whole Studio?

Comment: I have the full (pro?) VS.  I'm not looking for the Sp installer, but what the installer downloaded last time I ran it, to avoid the same download.

Comment: If it's from the website here: 
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=FBEE1648-7106-44A7-9649-6D9F6D58056E&displaylang=en
It is in your Temp folder (in XP):
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1

Comment: Also, they seem to delete after the install, so you need to copy them during the install.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but you can try searching under these paths:

%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp
(probably %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 SP1)

You can also try to search for this file: VS90sp1-KB945140-ENU.exe

(it may reside under %TEMP%\VS90sp1-KB945140-ENU.exe)

Comment: I have the file you mention, but that is the installer.  It starts a long download, which it has done before, and I would like to avoid redoing that download.

Comment: Try to do a search for files (all files) under %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Temp and then sort by size descending. Look for some really big files.